# How to draw Skewed textview Android

Tags: android

If there any way to draw skewed text in Android? I've tried to play with `Canvas.skew(dx, dy)` and `Matrix.preSkew(...)` and `Matrix.postSkew(...)` in onDraw() method of my textview. But with no results. Here is an example of what I have:

[image: source textview]

And here is an example of what I want to implement:

[image: this is a goal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `Paint.setTextSkewX(float skewX)` method. Here is an example.

```
// call in onDraw(Canvas canvas)
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setTextSkewX(-0.2f);
canvas.drawText("some text", 0, 0, paint);
```

Comment: Don't create your Paint in onDraw, create it in an init method and reuse it in onDraw. Only thing that should be in onDraw is "canvas.drawText(...);" !!!

Comment: This only skews the text, not the shape. This accepted answer doesn't seem to answer the question.