# Rotate TextView word without rotating the letters

Tags: android

I have a problem. Perhaps I am missing the correct search terminology to Google it correctly or no one did it before. How do I rotate a `TextView` word without rotating the letters?

This is what I currently have by calling the rotate function in the xml:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Does anyone has an idea how to do this? Is it possible with native methods? If not, then how is it possible?

Cheers

Comment: so, you want a **skew** effect!

Comment: I guess, it would be not done by rotation only, you need to stretch it somehow

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375130/skewing-a-text-view-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746496/how-to-draw-skewed-textview-android and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#skew(float, float)

Comment: Awesome Golem. I think that will do it! I will test it later and tell you if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a TextView for each letter and put them into any Viewgroup. Then you rotate the Viewgroup to the left and rotate each letter to the right at the same time and speed.

Comment: What an overkill! This solution is both hard to implement and time consuming.

Comment: Just because you can and because it works that doesn't mean you should. And this is in fact a supa-overkill

Comment: Well, you shouldn't choose a way just because it brings you to your destination, if it takes you longer time and makes you victim of the criminals. You should prefer the fastest and cheapest way.

Comment: Thank you for the approach but as Pedro and Golem already mentioned that's the last way I should go. But yes it's a way.

Comment: Remember: the difference between a sailor and a **good** sailor is in the route he chooses.

Comment: This solution isn't an overkill because it isn't called all the time and nowadays Android devices can do something like that. However you all are right, there are better ways to do that, but if anyone works, there is the last chance, and this will help.

Comment: `nowadays Android devices can do something like that.` Not at all. There are still low performing devices around. I still **proudly** behold a Huawei Ideos - U8150 (`Android 2.2, 240*320px, ldpi, 600 MHz monocore`). And it still gives me great feedback. It's an **invaluable testing device** to **optimize** my code. And even though it **can** run such code, I would surely feed it with a better code.